# What is a "cike" as in "taking the cike"?

Tags: etymology, phrases

In the novel Dracula I came upon the following sentence:

> "But the old Chapel, that *took the cike* that did. "

Presumably that is an equivalent phrase to "took the biscuit". But a google search for "cike" just showed up [this unlikely definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cike).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the idiom "takes the *cake*" spelled to indicate a strong accent in the speaker.

Comment: Like the fake ad for deck maintenance from New Zealand I just watched ;)))

Comment: I'd never actually heard of "taking the cake" before.

Comment: The [whole paragraph](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/345/345-h/345-h.htm) is in written in 'accent': “That ’ere ’ouse, guv’nor, is the rummiest I ever was in. Blyme! but it ain’t been touched sence a hundred years. There was dust that thick in the place that you might have slep’ on it without ’urtin’ of yer bones; an’ the place was that neglected that yer might ’ave smelled ole Jerusalem in it. But the ole chapel—that took the cike, that did! Me and my mate, we thort we wouldn’t never git out quick enough. Lor’, I wouldn’t take less nor a quid a moment to stay there arter dark.”

Comment: @Hugo You're right. Makes sense now.